# Mono Sybase dll not found

Tags: mono, sap-ase

I just installed the mono last version and the mono develop, here http://www.mono-project.com/Sybase they refer the dll Mono.Data.SybaseClient, but I can't find it anywhere, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sybase client library has been dropped in [Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8#Removed_Library%3a_Mono.Data.SybaseClient) due to lack of users.

Comment: So, how can I connect to sybase ? can u help me ?

Comment: You are using commercial database software, start by reaching out to your vendor. There's also a DataDirect ADO.Net provider ( http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net-for-sybase/index.html ), I had very good results with their Oracle connector on Mono - I'm guessing this would be similar.

Comment: @crassr3cords: Sybase has a free ODBC dll/so, so you can use System.Data.Odbc ;)